# Swapping Pairs in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So i've got this function to swap pairs of numbers in haskell, and i don't know what i've done wrong, maybe you guys can give me a hand.
SO basically this function gets a list, say, [1,2,3,4,5], and returns the numbers swapped by pairs, something like, [2,1,4,3,5]. if the number of elements is odd, the last element stays the same.

Here's what i've done:

```
swapPairs :: [a] -> [a]
swapPairs (x:xs) = [!!x = !!x+1 && !!x+1 = !!x| x <- xs]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-- Return first two elements in inverted order, recusively call for remaining list,
-- only matches lists of two or more elements
swapPairs (a:b:xs) = b : a : swapPairs xs
-- Return tail for zero or one remaining elements
swapPairs (xs)     = xs
```

Comment: I'm not understanding very well the second line...why is it necessary ? aren't we doing already a recursive call on the first line ?

Comment: That last line is needed to match a list with 1 or 0 elements. In those cases, no swapping is needed, so it just returns the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern matching to fetch 2 head elements:

```
swapPairs (x:y:xs) = y : x : (swapPairs xs)
```

Comment: You're missing the termination of the recursive call.

Comment: @JensErat, I wasn't intended to write all the code for author.